# How to get the Clone Id

Tags: jquery, html

```
function drop(ev)
{
     ev.preventDefault();
     var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
     ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true)); 
}
```

Html  code

```
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

I need to increase the image width. for that i need the clone id . how to get that clone id in this code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give your clone a new ID yourself, otherwise it'll (incorrectly) possess the same ID as the original node:

```
var clone = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
clone.id = ...;
ev.target.appendChild(clone);
```